# how can I manage memory in librdkafka?

Tags: c, apache-kafka, memory-management, librdkafka

I am developing a high-performance program that is a `librdkafka` producer. I want to manage the memory of `librdkafka` so that I know the status of the memory of the software. to do this I defined a free list and registered a delivery report function for the`dr_msg_cb` function. each time I want to produce a message, `rd_kafka_producev` will be used with `RD_KAFKA_V_OPAQUE(my_free_list)`. so in the delivery report function, we have the pointer of the free list in the `msg->_private` variable and the pointer of the message in `msg->payload`. So we can release that item to the free list.
my question is in which error code should I release that message to the free list? We know that in some error codes, `librdkafka` still needs the pointer of the message and in some of them, `librdkafka` has nothing to do with that pointer.
How should I know those error codes?

[@edenhill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1821055/edenhill)